# git stash error: cannot record working tree state

Tags: git

I made some changes on several files. When I wanted to stash:

```
 git stash
```

I got an error message as below:

```
fatal: f89cf6f6dae11b4fa28fea6e8ac8e272782c5995 is not a valid object
Cannot record working tree state
```

By checking status:

```
git status
```

it gave me:

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   file1
        modified:   file2
        modified:   file3

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        fileA
        fileB
        dirA/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I know there is a way to use < checkout -- files >, but is there a way with stash? or other way to put aside changes and then pull from origin.
Thanks.

Comment: `git status` shows there are modified files. Are these the changes from your stash? Or are these the changes you are attempting to save as a stash?

Comment: You show the output from running a `git stash` command, but not the actual command itself. Can you edit the command itself into the question?

Comment: Those file1~3 are the  changes I would like to save as a stash and restore the working directory to my latest commit. But I somehow couldn't stash those away.